# Volley error handling generalized

Tags: android, httpresponse, android-volley

in my application, I've been thinking of the best way to implement 5xx responses from the server.

The first approach was to write my own version of the `Request.deliverError` method as attached:

```
@Override
public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
    if(error.networkResponse == null){
        super.deliverError(error);
        return;
    }else {
        switch(error.networkResponse.statusCode){
            case HttpStatus.SC_HTTP_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                AppInfo.reportDevInfo(GlideApplication.applicationContext, "got a 505 response for request" +this.toString(), null);
                break;
            case HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR:
            case HttpStatus.SC_BAD_GATEWAY:
            case HttpStatus.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE:
            case HttpStatus.SC_GATEWAY_TIMEOUT:
                int retryCount = RETRY_COUNT - getRetryPolicy().getCurrentRetryCount();
                if(retryCount < 0) {
                    super.deliverError(error);
                    return;
                }
                String backoff = error.networkResponse.getHeaders.get("Retry-After");
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(backoof) == false) {
                    attemptRetryWithNewBackoff(backoff);
                    return;
                }
                break;
            }
                super.deliverError(error)
        }
    }
}
```

but that only caused ANRs in the application.

Looking at further research, I found [this blog post](https://github.com/smanikandan14/Volley-demo#handling-error-codes) that showed a way of handling the different response codes, the only issue, is that I'm not sure how to generalise this to my entire application and implementing handling of 5xx response codes with the appropriate "Retry-After" heade.

Having a class that implements `ErrorListener` and gets a different one as a param in the constructor seems very costly and inefficient:

```
public class MyErrorListener implements ErrorListener {
    ErrorListener mListener;

    public MyErrorListener(ErrorListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        if(handleFiveHundredResponse(error) == false) {
            this.mListener.onErrorResponse(error);
        }
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is a bit late, but I'm sure it will definitely help newbies looking for this and This is what I do.

### In Kotlin :

**Request**

```
val request = object : JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
    url,
    reqObj,
    {}, { error ->
        Toast.makeText(this, getVolleyError(error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }) {
}
RequestController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request)
```

**getVolleyError(error: VolleyError)**

```
fun Activity.getVolleyError(error: VolleyError): String {
    var errorMsg = ""
    if (error is NoConnectionError) {
        val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        var activeNetwork: NetworkInfo? = null
        activeNetwork = cm.activeNetworkInfo
        errorMsg = if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting) {
           "Server is not connected to the internet. Please try again"
        } else {
           "Your device is not connected to internet.please try again with active internet connection"
        }
    } else if (error is NetworkError || error.cause is ConnectException) {
        errorMsg = "Your device is not connected to internet.please try again with active internet connection"
    } else if (error.cause is MalformedURLException) {
        errorMsg = "That was a bad request please try again…"
    } else if (error is ParseError || error.cause is IllegalStateException || error.cause is JSONException || error.cause is XmlPullParserException) {
        errorMsg = "There was an error parsing data…"
    } else if (error.cause is OutOfMemoryError) {
        errorMsg = "Device out of memory"
    } else if (error is AuthFailureError) {
        errorMsg = "Failed to authenticate user at the server, please contact support"
    } else if (error is ServerError || error.cause is ServerError) {
        errorMsg = "Internal server error occurred please try again...."
    } else if (error is TimeoutError || error.cause is SocketTimeoutException || error.cause is ConnectTimeoutException || error.cause is SocketException || (error.cause!!.message != null && error.cause!!.message!!.contains(
            "Your connection has timed out, please try again"
        ))
    ) {
        errorMsg = "Your connection has timed out, please try again"
    } else {
        errorMsg = "An unknown error occurred during the operation, please try again"
    }
    return errorMsg
}
```

The method I used above is an extension function of kotlin, which can only be called from an activity, if you want to call the same method from another scope, then you have to modify it. an instance of an activity is mandatory to check the internet connectivity

### In Java:

**Request**

```
JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,"url",null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response){

        }
        },new Response.ErrorListener(){
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
        Toast.makeText(this, getVolleyError(error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        });
        RequestController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
```

**getVolleyError(VolleyError error)**

```
public String getVolleyError(VolleyError error){
        String errorMsg="";
        if(error instanceof NoConnectionError){
        ConnectivityManager cm=(ConnectivityManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork=null;
        if(cm!=null){
        activeNetwork=cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        }
        if(activeNetwork!=null&&activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
        errorMsg="Server is not connected to internet.kindly try agian";
        }else{
        errorMsg="Your device is not connected to internet.please try again with active internet connection";
        }
        }else if(error instanceof NetworkError||error.getCause()instanceof ConnectException){
        errorMsg="Your device is not connected to the internet.";
        }else if(error.getCause()instanceof MalformedURLException){
        errorMsg="That was a bad request please try again...";
        }else if(error instanceof ParseError||error.getCause()instanceof IllegalStateException
        ||error.getCause()instanceof JSONException
        ||error.getCause()instanceof XmlPullParserException){
        errorMsg="There was an error parsing data...";
        }else if(error.getCause()instanceof OutOfMemoryError){
        errorMsg="Device out of memory";
        }else if(error instanceof AuthFailureError){
        errorMsg="Failed to authenticate user at the server, please contact support";
        }else if(error instanceof ServerError||error.getCause()instanceof ServerError){
        errorMsg="Internal server error occurred please try again....";
        }else if(error instanceof TimeoutError||error.getCause()instanceof SocketTimeoutException
        ||error.getCause()instanceof ConnectTimeoutException
        ||error.getCause()instanceof SocketException
        ||(error.getCause().getMessage()!=null
        &&error.getCause().getMessage().contains("Connection timed out"))){
        errorMsg="Your connection has timed out, please try again";
        }else{
        errorMsg="Sorry, some thing weird occurred";
        }
        return errorMsg;
        }
```

The method above should need an instance of an activity to check connectivity, you can provide it as per your logic

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented my own ErrorListener which handle server error responses, here is the code:

```
public class MyErrorListener  implements Response.ErrorListener {

    Context context;

    View errorView;

    TextView errorText;


    public MyErrorListener(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the preparation to show the errors
     */
    public void responsePreparation(){

    }

    /**
     * Handle the client Errors
     * @param error
     */
    public void clientErrors(int error){
        switch(error) {
            case 400:
                errorText.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_400_registration));

                AlertDialog.Builder error400 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                error400.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_400_title_registration));
                error400.setView(errorView);
                error400.create();
                error400.show();
                break;
            case 401:
                errorText.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_401_registration));

                AlertDialog.Builder error401 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                error401.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.error_401_title_registration));
                error401.setView(errorView);
                error401.create();
                error401.show();
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
        errorView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.error_dialog, null);
        errorText = (TextView) errorView.findViewById(R.id.error_dialog_text);
        responsePreparation();

        if(response != null && response.data != null){
            Log.v("Status code", String.valueOf(error.networkResponse.statusCode));
            switch(response.statusCode){
                case 400:
                case 401:
                    clientErrors(response.statusCode);
                    break;
                case 500:
                    errorText.setText(context.getString(R.string.error_502));

                    AlertDialog.Builder error500 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    error500.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_502_title));
                    error500.setView(errorView);
                    error500.create();
                    error500.show();
                    break;
                case 502:
                    errorText.setText(context.getString(R.string.error_502));

                    AlertDialog.Builder error502 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    error502.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_502_title));
                    error502.setView(errorView);
                    error502.create();
                    error502.show();
                    break;

            }
        }
        else{
            if(checkConnection()){
                errorText.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_502));

                AlertDialog.Builder timeoutErrorServer = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                timeoutErrorServer.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_502_title));
                timeoutErrorServer.setView(errorView);
                timeoutErrorServer.create();
                timeoutErrorServer.show();

            }
            else{
                errorText.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.timeout_error));

                AlertDialog.Builder timeoutError = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                timeoutError.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.timeout_error_title));
                timeoutError.setView(errorView);
                timeoutError.create();
                timeoutError.show();
            }

        }

    }

    /**
     * Gets the view of the dialog to show
     * @return
     */
    public View getDialogView(){
        return errorView;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the error text to show
     * @return
     */
    public TextView getErrorText(){
        return errorText;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the user have got connection
     * @return Boolean
     */
    private Boolean checkConnection(){
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return !(i == null || !i.isConnected() || !i.isAvailable());
    }

}
```

You can add to the switch the error codes that you want.

Then, when I want to make a new VolleyQuery, I override responsePreparation and clientErrors, like this example:

```
jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody, listener, new MyErrorListener(context){

        @Override
        public void responsePreparation() {
            showProgress(false);

        }

        @Override
        public void clientErrors(int error) {
            Log.v("Error message", String.valueOf(error));
            switch(error) {
                case 400:
                    getErrorText().setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_400_registration));

                    AlertDialog.Builder error400 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    error400.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_400_title_registration));
                    error400.setView(getDialogView());
                    error400.create();
                    error400.show();
                    break;
                case 401:
                    getErrorText().setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_401_registration));

                    AlertDialog.Builder error401 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    error401.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.error_401_title_registration));
                    error401.setView(getDialogView());
                    error401.create();
                    error401.show();
                    break;
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                        } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                        }
                    }
                }
```